# Form of the word "repeal?"

Tags: american-english

If someone were to say something got destroyed, they would say "the **destruction** of the..." What is this form for "repeal?"

Comment: Hi Vikram, welcome to EL&U. We ask that users do some research of their own (e.g. check in a dictionary) first, and only ask here if the solution can't be found. Any dictionary will show that *repeal* is also a noun, hence "the *repeal* of..." would suit your context. I'm voting to close this question for lack of research. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the [Tour]. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeal is also a noun :)

You can say "the repeal of something"

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/repeal

Answer (score 1):

**Repeal** can be a verb or noun. So the answer is repeal.

Example:

> > President Franklin D. Roosevelt announces the Repeal of Prohibition.
> >
> > .The 21st Amendment repealed the 18th Amendment ...

https://www.archives.gov/historical-docs/todays-doc/?dod-date=1205